Dask change divisions when write to_parquet file
Work with dask dataframe:

Read parquet file with two column - ddf.
Set index (based on existing column).
ddf.compute_current_divisions() return divisions like [0, 1000000, 2000000, 3000000, ...]
Calculate new columns using map_partitions.
ddf.compute_current_divisions() return divisions like [0, 1000000, 2000000, 3000000, ...]
Save ddf to parquet.
Read saved file (readed_ddf = dd.read_parquet()).
Readed dataframe has another partitions like [0, 2000000, 4000000, 6000000, ...]

Please, say, how divisions are chosen in to_parquet function?
Or this behavior is a bug?

Hi, do you think you could provide a reproducer?
